# Template selectors in ember js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an objects array of different types and I want to display a different view for each according to its type, somthing like this

```
{{#each vehicle}}
    <!-- specific view depending on vehicle type -->
{{/each}}
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Partials

I think you're wanting to render a specific template based on some property of your model. The attributes that helpers like `partial` take can be dynamic. Here's an example of rendering a certain partial based on the 'type' of vehicle:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qemewu/edit?html,js,output

### Using a Component

You can also dynamically modify the `templateName` of a component if the partial doesn't do it for you and you need more control:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qemewu/edit

How cool is that?